# Pandas can't read the cell value

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column incloudYes or No
i need to count how many Yes  when i write this code
df.loc[df['Q']=='Yes']
impty df

and i need to [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jTLo.png)add new column incloudnumber 1 if column Q incloud Yes

df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\oppo\Downloads\On Site Customer ROs Questionnaire V2.0 (1).xlsx')
df=df[['8.Are you aware of OPPO service day on 10-12th each month?']]
df=df.rename(columns={'8.Are you aware of OPPO service day on 10-12th each month?':'Q'})
df.loc[df['Q']=='Yes','awere']=1
df

Comment: If you want to count all values: `df['Q'].value_counts()`, for just "Yes": `df['Q'].eq('Yes').sum()`. If you want a flag: `df['new'] = df['Q'].eq('Yes').astype(int)` or `df.loc[df['Q'].eq('Yes'), 'new] = 1`. Makre sure you don't have leading/trailing spaces. IF you do, remove them with: `df['Q'] = df['Q'].str.strip()`.